# how to get linux command execution result or message

Tags: php, linux, shell, jquery, wkhtmltopdf

I am using this code and want to convert html to pdf. I am on Linux.

I am using Ajax on client side and PHP is server side script.

no any error is coming. PHP code and Ajax code is working fine..

with `PHP` code `PDF` is converting successfully. but after conversion PDF how could i get message is that PDF is converted or not converted or error are there.

I also checked output of `shell_exec()` but "**`Null`**" is coming in both case when PDF is converted and not converted.

Simply i need any Boolean value or some message which will address the state. 
How could i get that.

```
 <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', '1');

        $url = $_POST['sendUrl'];
        $cmd = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf ".$url." /tmp/google1.pdf";
        $t = shell_exec($cmd);
        var_dump($t);

        exit();
```

Comment: is wkhtmltopdf just writing to stderr on error and not to stdout?

Comment: no no any error is coming.. php code and ajax code is working fine..

Comment: I know exec() if you define a second parameter (an array) it will fill that array with the responses. e.g. exec($command, $response); print_r($response);

Comment: @Karl   Should i replace shell_exec() with exec() ??

Comment: You could try it, I'm not sure if it will give the desired response as I know nothing about wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: i have tried.. but in all conditions $response   having blank array

Comment: Strange, have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php if you pass in a third parameter you can even get the return response, maybe that will help?

Answer (score -1):

The return value will be the string if the command is executed success without any error. If execution have error, the return value is null.

You have to check the shell_exec() return value like

```
$t = shell_exec($cmd);

if($t === null)
  echo "error";
else
  echo "success";
```

from the ajax return value you can come to know the result.

hope it will help.